# How to set the last directory in "mail_location" setting of dovecot?

Tags: dovecot, maildir

I have:

```
mail_location = maildir:/srv/vmail/%d/%n
```

However in reality, Dovecot stores mails in: `/srv/vmail/%d/%n/mail`

I need to migrate a mailboxes that ends with "Maildir" instead of "mail". How can I change the last part of this URI from "mail" to "Maildir" so I can migrate mailboxes without actually changing names of those directories?

Comment: It's seems to me that MTA stores the messages, not dovecot. When dovecot do, there is no "mail" suffix if location ends with %d/%n

Comment: what is the value of home_mailbox ? best is to post postconf -nf postconf -Mf and dovecot -n after the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, thanks for your comment Kondybas, it helped me to figure this out. I forgot, that mailboxes locations were aliased by postfix from MySQL database, managed by [ViMbAdmin](http://www.vimbadmin.net/). It seems that ViMbAdmin sets those locations based on default value of "defaults.mailbox.maildir" variable in its config file, and doesn't have an option that would allow to change it later from UI, so I just changed this default value and edited existing records in database. Now everything is sorted out :) .

Comment: But why do you want an extra part in the path? Isn't it meaningless?

Comment: It probably is, but I'm migrating a mailbox structure that has this extra part, and I think wasting time for changing this structure would be even more meaningless if I can change just postfix setting :) .

Comment: It's way better to move LDA functionality to the dovecot. You'll get many features like sieve filtering, quotas and autoresponder. LDA from postfix is rudimentary and should be used in the simplest cases only.